# How to use Hashicorp Vault like login to web site

Tags: rest, debian, hashicorp-vault

I need advice about how can I use Vault login for web. I have set up Debian 8 server. On that server run web page (hashi-ui) for manage Nomad and Consul. Web page work and I can access it. But there is no login so everyone can access to this web page. So I need set up login and authenticate of users. I want use Vault that run on server too. I need result like if I access web page via web browser so after enter URL, web browser pop up login form (Like if you want call some REST and service need authenticate user, so web browser pop up default login form). I enable user-pass method in Vault. I set username and password, but now I do not know how to set up for this web page.

How can I set this user-pass method to authenticate user and then give access to web?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Your use case is not really what Vault is for. You are looking for a user management system - hashed passwords in a database. Vault is more for storing the secrets that your web app would need, like the password for the database itself.

Comment: OK, thank you. I though, I can use REST api like call http://"web_address"/"auth". Then web browser pop up login form and after pass valid input I will be redirect to my web page. Something like that. I do not want public access to this web page, but only for admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an unusual use case, I don't believe you can use Vault directly for it.

Perhaps with PGP, you could use a web interface to keep exchanging encrypted messages with an agent that can proxy your authentication, read, write requests somehow to Vault and transmit them back for you, preferably encrypted. Doing sealing, unsealing like this might be tricky, you might risk getting yourself locked out from sealing if the proxy agent is unreachable or refuses your requests.

Comment: Thank you, I will use another way than Vault.

Comment: You don't have to give up on Vault, just that it's scope probably will never go to the extent of making this possible. I am sure people will be using Slack chat bots and web UIs to interact with it however, though you must either build that yourself or find some managed solution that might already exist there.